# Android get package name of current opened application

Tags: android, package-managers, custom-keyboard

I am working with custom keyboard ,I need current package name when keyboard is open . This keyboard will be open with different different application ,so i need that application package name which is open currently. I am using following code but its not working properly.

```
   ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager)PhotoActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 20){
                String mPackageName = mActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses().get(0).processName;
                Log.e("Checking package:      ","Checking current application package"+mPackageName);
            }
            else{
                String mPackageName = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
            }
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of about a thousand questions.  FYI, the hack you're using was broken in Android 5.1.1 and 6.0.  The officially sanctioned replacement is the Usage Stats API, but it's not available on all devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getting current package name in android

```
     ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
     List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);

// display the current class name
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;

// current class package name
             String packageName = componentInfo.getPackageName();
```

add this to your project manifest permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);

Log.d("current task :", "CURRENT Activity ::" + taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName());
```

Comment: This hack was broken in Android 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:-

```
 ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List l = am.getRecentTasks(1, ActivityManager.RECENT_WITH_EXCLUDED);
Iterator i = l.iterator();
PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo info = (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo)(i.next());
    try {
        CharSequence c = pm.getApplicationLabel(pm.getApplicationInfo(
        info.processName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
        Log.w("LABEL", c.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Name Not FOund Exception
    }
}
```

And do not forget to use the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
```

Comment: Hi Ravindra Kushwaha, Thanks for reply. It is not working properly as it gets same package name of custom keyboard instead of current running open application. I am using in Android 5.0

Comment: @SakibSyed ...Ok...let me try...